# Powershell Rest API problems to deliver Parameter

Tags: powershell, rest, curl

I am trying to translate a working CURL WebRequest into using pure powershell. Unfortunately I don't know what the parameter in Powershell is that replaces the CURL parameter `--data`.

The authentication (and simpler post requests I've already done with Powershell and REST) but for the specific CURL request I can't get the translation to Powershell right.

This is the working CURL Request:

```
curl -k https://RestAPI-URL -X GET -H "auth: Basic <Token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"net_cidr\":\"10.0.0.0/8\"}"
```

And this is the Powershell-Translation (Using PS-Version 5.1):

```
$json = ConvertTo-Json (@{"username"="Test";"password"="Test";})
$token = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://RestAPI-URL"  -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST).content | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

$token = $token.access_token
$header = @{auth="Basic $token"}


$Parameters = @{
  net_cidr = '10.0.0.0/8'
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://RestAPI-URL" -Headers $header -body $Parameters -Method GET -ContentType "application/json"
```

Error-Ouput from Webrequest trough Powershell:

> FAILED: Please provide all parameters: net_id

Comment: Are you sure the URLs are the same with all the paths?

Comment: Yes, I have already tested that. The request arrives on the webserver, which even reports that the parameter of the network-ID is missing. So the part which is intercepted by the CURL with "--data" is missing/failing with my powershellscript or is delivered wrong.

Comment: you are passing `net_cidr` in body of both curl and Invoke-RestMethod... not sure what that would have to do with `net_id`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with another API. I used the method below to troubleshoot it. Run this code and report what you see. You may have to include this net_id param. In my case I was missing a mandatory param that was not in the REST documentation for the app I was working with.

Below I put your code into function REST-CALL, then I included a function to help us understand the error (Get-ErrorFromResponseBody). We try the invoke-restmethod cmdlet, and on error it is caught and handled by Get-ErrorFromResponseBody. While this isn't quite your answer, it is a step towards it. I will update this after you report back what the response is.

```
function REST-CALL(){
    $json = ConvertTo-Json (@{"username"="Test";"password"="Test"})
    $token = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://RestAPI-URL"  -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST).content | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

    $token = $token.access_token
    $header = @{auth="Basic $token"}

$Parameters = @{
  net_cidr = '10.0.0.0/8'
}

        try{
            $global:site = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://RestAPI-URL" -Headers $header -body $Parameters -Method POST -ContentType "application/json"

        }
        catch{
            write-host "An exception occurred: The request did not complete."
            Get-ErrorFromResponseBody($_)
        }
}

Function Get-ErrorFromResponseBody($ErrorMessage) {
    #Determine if we are using PowerShell v5.1 and lower exception handling
    if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 6) {
        if ($Error.Exception.Response) {  
            $Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($ErrorMessage.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream())
            $Reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
            $Reader.DiscardBufferedData()
            $ResponseBody = $Reader.ReadToEnd()
            if ($ResponseBody.StartsWith('{')) {
                $ResponseBody = $ResponseBody | ConvertFrom-Json
            }
            return $ResponseBody
        }
    }
    else {
        return $ErrorMessage.ErrorDetails.Message
    }
}

REST-CALL
```

"The --data flag should be for defining POST data." So I feel strongly you should try a POST method.

Comment: i've tried your code and the responde from the variable $global:site is still:
FAILED: Please provide all parameters: net_id

I'll look into the API documentary, maybe I can find something out. I find it strange that it works with CURL. But I had already experienced some strange actions with CURL, for example the automatic fallback of methods if they don't work ;-)

Comment: so i found out the net_id is actually the net_cidr...we deliver this one with the parameters in the Body part... but somehow the API does not accept it.
Does it have to be sent in the header or with another 'method'?

it would be nice to know what the CURL '--data' header is in Powershell-REST.

Comment: Updated the script above as I was sending $parameters instead of $json as the payload. If we don't include $json the user ID and pass won't be passed. I believe --data is for POST rather than get, have you tried POST? I'll look into this more. In the meantime try the updated code above, and also try changing GET to POST.

Comment: --data is supposed to be with sending POST. Try POST instead of GET. Updated the code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.
I see that as you, according to my interpretation of the CURL docu, --data is a POST method within a Get or other method.
Unfortunately I have already tried all methods with Powershell:

Output: 405 The method is not allowed for the requested URL. 

Well if it doesn't work I get the data with CURL and process it with powershell...

Comment: What application are you making calls to? Perhaps we could seek out some documentation on that param?

Comment: The Application is "BlueCat DNS Integrity™ Gateway"  - BlueCat API